# Switching between a UITabBarController and a UIViewController (iOS Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I've spent ages stuck on this: Using the Tab Bar template (without storyboard) I can easily switch between tabs and switch between views within each table, however when it comes to swapping between a `UITabBarController` and a `UIViewController` whatever code i keep trying won't work.

```
-(IBAction)tabtoview:(id)sender{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                           forView:self.view
                             cache:YES];
    [self.tabBarController removeFromParentViewController];   
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainscreen]; //Crashes here
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Rather than removing the `tabBarController` it would be preferable if I could hide/disable it after having animated. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: what is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: SIGABRT - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6dae9f0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you problem is that `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` are those kind of controllers that cannot be handled the way you are doing.

You'd better subclass your `UIWindow` in `app delegate` and move the `-(IBAction)tabtoview:(id)sender;` method into the subclass of `UIWindow`. I tried and it works.

The reason is, **you must have a controller to take the responsibility of switching views**. What you are trying to do is, swapping controllers, rather than views. And that's a conflict. Tabs are part of `UITabController`, they are not views! It is also the same story for `UINavigationController`.

So, if you are simply swapping views, you can do it right in one of your viewControllers, but swpaping a controller with another (i.e. `UIViewcontroller` with `UITabBarController`) should be handled in a higher level, i.e. app delegate. The only instance available in that level is your `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIApplication mainScreen] bounds]];  
[self presentModalViewController:v animated:YES];
```

I think it should work